# C# Dev Express Ribbon Form - Ribbon Page Group With Combo Box?

Tags: c#, devexpress, ribbon-form

Has anyone managed to implement a series (3 is possible) of comboboxes as part of a RibbonPageGroup on a Dev Express Ribbon Form?!

I would really appreciate any help or advice people have to offer relating to this particular implementation....really struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add them by selecting the AddEditor then selecting comboboxedit

try to post this question on their support website: 
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/